# AJAX returns wrong charset in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encoding, iso-8859-1

**What I'm trying to do**

I am using $.get() on index.html page to get the contents of otherpage.html located on the same server and then display it in a `DIV` on index.html page. Both pages contain some accented characters (think Spanish, French and German) and are encoded with `iso-8859-1`.

Since both pages are generated with a 3rd party 'wysiwyg html authoring tool', I cannot change the encoding of the pages and I have no control over how servers are setup. I can only add my JS code.

**So what went wrong?**

It all works perfect in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera. However, IE10/9/8/7 returns garbled text. I get empty squares `` ` instead of ``ö`,`å`and`ä`. I have searched all of Stackoverflow (ISO-8859-1 seems to cause a lot of headache) and my code includes most of those tips for enforcing encoding in headers etc. No success :(

**Ok, show us your code!**

I have setup test case on two servers: [test one](http://goo.gl/5C6zE) and [test two](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11433463/stack/index.html). The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>the first page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-1">
function GetData() {

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=iso-8859-1')
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Accept','text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
    },
    timeout:5000,
    contentType: 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
    dataType: 'html',
    mimeType: 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
    processData: false
})

$.post( 'otherpage.html' )
 .done( function(pagedata) { 
    console.log(pagedata)
    $('#result').html(pagedata);
 })
 .fail( function() { 
    $('#result').html('Request failed');
 })

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Get data" onclick="GetData()">
<div id="intro">Some characters: ö--å--ä.</div>
<div id="result">Click "Get data".</div>
</body>
</html>
```

otherpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>the other page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hälsyt högg lått Xöööööööööz Zååååååååååååy Kääääääääääännn </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**So your question is...?**

What should I do in Javascript to make sure the text display correctly in IE10/9/8/7? I appreciate any constructive ideas.

Answer (score 0):

IE screws up ISO-8859-1 encoding. Try using ISO-8859-15 encoding which is `almost` like ISO-8859-1.
If that doesn't help, try setting document.charset="ISO-8859-1" in onsubmit handler of your callback for IE (for other browsers, `<form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">` should do the trick

P.S. I haven't yet run the code provided.